# Can't see how this simple SQL query is 'malformed'!

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

```
     QueryText = string.Format("SELECT {0}, {1} Path FROM Scope() "
                                + "WHERE {0} = 'test' AND {1} BETWEEN '"
                                + minimumDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' AND '" + maximumDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                                + "' ORDER BY {1} Desc", "TestField", "DateField");
```

minimumDate and maximumDate are of type DateTime (.net DateTime). This Is a FullTextSQLQuery.

NOTE: Prior to adding the date between clause - this query was fine, so the fields definitely exist etc.

EDIT: Actual query string:

```
"SELECT TestField, DateField FROM Scope() WHERE TestField = 'test' AND DateField BETWEEN '2011-06-30 09:41:23' AND '2012-06-29 09:41:23' ORDER BY DateField  Desc"
```

EDIT: I've made a mistake by stating it had worked prior to the between clause - I must've tampered with the select because I omitted an important comma.

Comment: what is your actual `QuerText` after replacing

Comment: Please always use SqlParameter instead of string concatenation. You will avoid a lot of headache. SqlParameters will help you to properly convert types to actual SQL query, without having to deal with custom schemas. And your code will be far more readable.

Comment: See OP. @SteveB - parameters possible with FullTextSQLQuerys?

Comment: @DeeMac: I don't know. I never tried:) I haven't see this part of your question. Please try and give us the result of your experiment :)

Comment: @DeeMac no, but that *isn't* a full text query... but SteveB is right; parameters would be far preferable

Comment: can you pass the exception message ? and wich provider are you using ? sqlserver, mysql, ... ?

Comment: @MarcGravell - this is the QueryText property of type FullTextSQLQuery. If using parameters is an option I'll obviously opt for that but it doesn't appear to be.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing comma before Path.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot!! Assuming you actually meant comma!?

Comment: The fact that I don't understand what seems to be the correct answer concerns me.

Comment: Yes that's what i meant, English is not my first language :), I'll change it in the answer text.

Answer (score 2):

Use CONVERT() with dates:

```
BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, 'here put date', 120)  AND CONVERT(datetime, 'here put date', 120)
```

Comment: this is datetime format http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx  
You could also convert to datetime by passing only date and use 120 ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should not write your queries like that in .net. You should use db parameters:

```
string commandText = string.Format("SELECT {0}, {1} FROM Scope() "
                            + "WHERE {0} = 'test' AND {1} BETWEEN '@minDate' "
                            + "AND '@maxDate'"
                            + " ORDER BY {1} Desc", "TestField", "DateField");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@minDate", SqlDbType.SqlDateTime);
command.Parameters["@minDate"].Value = minimumDate;
command.Parameters.Add("@maxDate", SqlDbType.SqlDateTime);
command.Parameters["@maxDate"].Value = maximumDate;
```

Comment: @Downvoter, why downvote? Using parameters in sql statements is they way you should do it.